# vertica database remove inaccessible host

Tags: database, vertica

I am running a 3 node cluster of vertica 7. One of the nodes is down and the hardware is now inaccessible. To remove a host as described here https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ManageNodes/RemovingNodesFromADatabase.htm requires the host be accessible if it is part of a database so that projections among other things can be recalculated but the problem is I cannot bring the database up since I cannot access the hardware. Any suggestions? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you'll need to do an un-clean removal of the host. I would add a new one first.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a short step by step article on how this can be done. 
Follow the link [HOW TO RECOVER A LOST NODE IN VERTICA DATABASE](http://www.aodba.com/?p=3490&lang=en)

It is quite big to put it here, so ....

**Here is the list of steps:**
see the article for more details

- create new EC2 instance.
- install the required packages.
- download the vertica rpm and install it.
- create the dbadmin user and the verticadba group.
- enable password-less ssh access between the nodes for dbadmin user.
- create the same directory structure as in the lost node.
- copy admintools.conf file.
- create catalog location.
- recover the database using the force option.